# scrapy imagepipline: simple example created, what is command to run/test it

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I follow this docs to download images using scrapy.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html

Specifically, I would have this test.py:

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

from My.items import ImageItem

item = ImageItem()
item['image_urls'] = ['http://url/123.jpg']

class MySpider(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

My question is: what is command line I should run to test this test.py to verify if images are downloaded.

Further info:
I know the command "scrapy crawl project_name" but I prefer to test this test.py without having to create a project.

Also come across "scrapy runspider test.py" but it does not work. Error: MySpider not found.

Comment: If you want to run your spider from single script, try this snippet: [Self-contained script to crawl a site](http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/7/)

Comment: @SjaakTrekhaak, I've tested that snippet on `Scrapy 0.14.1`, it works.

Comment: @reclosedev you are right. I was having trouble using that in a child process instead of the main process  (signals can only be used in main thread); and confused that in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow [the tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/tutorial.html), because your script is lacking some important things eg. the callback for your Request() function. 
The tutorial is quite easy to complete in like 15 minutes, and will cover some aspects you are currently missing.

In order for pipelines and middlewares to work, you'd need the complete Scrapy engine.
I recommend to check out the [Architecture Overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/architecture.html) to get a feel of how the complete engine works.